# EF ObjectContext updating entity closed context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-update

I have some problems updating entities with ObjectContext. The context is closed when the update takes place so I need to attach it to a new context and then save it. However

```
  context.AttachTo(Navigation, item);
```

Takes about 10 seconds but it works. This is in my generic repository:

```
  using (var context = new Model(this._connectionString))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Objects.Count(); i++)
            {
                var item = Objects[i];
                context.AttachTo(Navigation, item);

                context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(item,  System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I only insert one item on this specific update.

I wonder if there is anything else I can do to make it go faster. Something like this:

```
  var previous = context.CreateObjectSet<EntityModel>()
                                .Where(s => s.ID == UpdatedItem.ID).FirstOrDefault<EntityModel>();
```

and then save it. If anyone know how to do it I would gladly accept your help :)

Thanks!

Comment: What is `previous` meaning/purpose? Is really your EF context class named `Model`? And your List named `Objects`? I don't think so. Post your real code please.

Comment: Please, try to give a better explanation of what you exactly do, how you do it, and what is what takes so long to execute. It's not clear at all. So the exact code of your repository, how you call it, how long it takes... If not, it's impossible to help you. BTW, why are you using the old ObjectContext instead of the new DbContext?